# How to `defun` a function in a package?

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm sorry, this is a very newbie Common Lisp question.

I'm learning common-lisp and package system.

I started with "The Complete Idiot's Guide to Common Lisp Packages" from http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/packages.html

In Chapter 1, the author defined a function `foo` in the package `:bob`

```
? (make-package :bob)
#<Package "BOB">
? (make-package :jane)
#<Package "JANE">
? (in-package bob)
#<Package "BOB">
? (defun foo () "This is Bob's foo")
FOO
```

I tested this code line by line in my REPL, but failed:

```
; SLIME 2.26
CL-USER> (make-package :bob)
#<PACKAGE "BOB">
CL-USER> (make-package :jane)
#<PACKAGE "JANE">
CL-USER> (in-package bob)
#<COMMON-LISP:PACKAGE "BOB">
BOB> (defun foo () "This is Bob's foo")
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (BOB::DEFUN BOB::FOO NIL "This is Bob's foo")
; 
; caught COMMON-LISP:STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: BOB::DEFUN
; 
; caught COMMON-LISP:WARNING:
;   undefined variable: BOB::FOO
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     DEFUN
;   Undefined variable:
;     FOO
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

And it told me:

```
The variable FOO is unbound.
   [Condition of type COMMON-LISP:UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
```

What's the problem?

How to fix this problem and make it work?

Very thanks.

PS: My environment is SBCL + quicklisp + slime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell Lisp which package to *use*. In standard Common Lisp it is unspecified which packages to *use*. SBCL *uses* none. If you want symbols of the package CL to be available, you have to explicitly *use* that package.

Package JANE

```
* (make-package :jane)
#<PACKAGE "JANE">
* (describe *)
#<PACKAGE "JANE">
  [package]


0 internal symbols.
```

For package BOB we use package CL:

```
* (make-package "BOB" :use '("CL"))
#<PACKAGE "BOB">
* (describe *)
#<PACKAGE "BOB">
  [package]


Use-list: COMMON-LISP
0 internal symbols.


* (find-symbol "DEFUN" "BOB")
DEFUN
:INHERITED
```

The symbol `DEFUN` is available in package BOB.

```
* (find-symbol "DEFUN" "JANE")
NIL
NIL
```

The symbol `DEFUN` is **NOT** available in package JANE.